# SML Combing two functions (min, max) into one (range)

Tags: list, range, sml

Anyway to combine these two functions which take a list and return the highest and lowest element. Want to output both at same time. Cheers

```
fun max[] = raise Empty 
    max[x] = x
    max(x::xs) =
  let 
    val y = max xs
  in
    if x > y then x else y
  end;

fun min[] = raise Empty 
  min[x] = x
  min(x::xs) =
     let 
       val y = min xs
     in
       if x < y then x else y
  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint. Use the same basic logic. Write a function `minmax` to return a pair of values of the form `(min,max)` and then in the recursive step, use pattern-matching to extract the two values. A template would be:

```
fun minmax [] = raise Empty
|   minmax [x] = (x,x)
|   minmax (x::xs) =
  let 
    val (a, b) = minmax xs
  in
    <fill in the code>
  end;
```

In the above `a` will be the min and `b` the max. Given `a` and `b` and a third value `x`, return either `(x,b)` or `(a,x)` or `(a,b)`, depending on how the inequalities play out. You will need more than one `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different hint: Use a helper function that stores the current (min, max) and return those when finished iterating. A template for that would be:

```
fun minmax [] = raise Empty
  | minmax (y::ys) =
    let fun helper [] (min, max) = ...
          | helper (x::xs) (min, max) = ...
    in helper ys (y, y) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thee approach sshine suggests is essentially a fold. Our state can be an `(int * int) option` value. An empty list wouldn't have a min or max, which we can represent as `NONE`. If the current state is `NONE`, clearly any value is both the minimum *and* the maximum. We can update this value depending on whether the current value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum.

It may help first to see how `foldl` can be implemented.

```
fun foldl _ init [] = init
  | foldl f init (x::xs) = 
    let
      val init' = f (x, init)
    in
      foldl f init' xs
    end;
```

```
fun minmax lst =
  let
    fun f(x, NONE) = SOME (x, x)
      | f(x, (acc as SOME (min, max))) =
        if x < min then SOME (x, max)
        else if x > max then SOME (min, x)
        else acc
  in
    foldl f NONE lst
  end;
```

If we evaluate `minmax [1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 0]` this now looks like:

```
minmax [1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 0]
foldl f NONE [1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 0]
foldl f (SOME (1, 1)) [2, 6, 3, 9, 0]
foldl f (SOME (1, 2)) [6, 3, 9, 0]
foldl f (SOME (1, 6)) [3, 9, 0]
foldl f (SOME (1, 6)) [9, 0]
foldl f (SOME (1, 9)) [0]
foldl f (SOME (0, 9)) []
SOME (0, 9)
```